# como Criar Array que atualiza a lista localStorage com Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

Olá pessoal boa Tarde como posso esta atualizando uma lista de dados no localstorage com Angular?
exemplo se na lista esta escrito 'Bruno' e não era 'Bruno' mas sim 'Paulo' como posso esta atualizando...

Comment: O ideal seria Você explicar um pouco mais o que você precisa, colocar exemplos do codigo (não colocar print) e algumas outras coisas que facilitaram para quem ver sua duvida poder te orientar.

Answer (score -2):

O LocalStorage funciona com base em salvar informações com chave e valor.
lembrando que os valores somente pode ser strings.

O método **setItem** armazena uma informação no localStorage
ex:

```
localStorage.setItem('professor', 'Eduardo antonio');
```

O método **getItem** recupera o valor salvo através do nome da chave
ex:

```
localStorage.getItem('professor');
```

O método **removeItem** remove o item através do nome da chave

```
localStorage.removeItem('professor');
```

Se pretende salvar um array no localStorage o ideal será transformar o array em string antes de salvar no storage e reverter quando pegar o item.

ex:

```
public getItemArray(chave) {
  let valor = localStorage.getItem(chave);
  if(!valor){
    return valor
  }
  let valorJson = JSON.parse(valor);
  return valorJson;
}

public setItemArray(chave, valor){
  if(!Array.isArray(valor)){
    return 
  }
  let valorString = JSON.stringify(valor);
  localStorage.setItem(chave, valorString);
}
```

Com o array em maos você pode editar como quiser os itens e salvar o novo array modificado.